# Determining function from expectation of its powers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimal-transport, moment-problem

I have a problem concerning reconstructing a function from the expectation of its powers.  The scalar version of this problem is as follows:

> Given a probability measure $\mu(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a sequence $(a_k)$, $k\in \{1,2,\dots\}$, find a function $f(x)$ such that $\int_x \left(f(x)\right)^k \mu(x) = a_k$.

The scalar version above is the warmup.  The question I am actually interested in is for a vector function:

> Given a probability measure $\mu(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a sequence $(A_k)$, $k\in \{1,2,\dots\}$, where $A_k$ is a symmetric tensor of order $k$, find a function $F: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\int_x \left(F(x)\right)^{\otimes k} \mu(x) = A_k$. (Where $(\cdots)^{\otimes k}$ denotes an iterated outer product.)

This problem originates from optimal transport, where it has to do with finding a transport map from moments of two distributions.  It bears resemblance to the [problem of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem), but I am unsure whether that connection is helpful.

**How can we find the function $F$ from the sequence $A_k$?  What is known about this problem?**

I will accept progress on the scalar version of the problem if the vector version proves too hard.

Comment: Well, at least for the scalar case, as you suggest this is equivalent to the moment problem. What kind of progress are you looking for on the scalar version?

Comment: @servabat I don't think it is equivalent to the moment problem.  The moment problem seeks to determine $\mu$ from the integrals $\int x^n \mu(x)$.  Here $\mu$ is known, and $\int f^k(x) \mu(x)$ has no obvious interpretation as moments.  If I'm missing something, please clarify.

Comment: I might be missing something, but if you solve the moment problem on $a_k$, which gives you a measure $\nu$, you solved the problem. Now, any function $f$ such that $f_\#\mu=\nu$ solves the problem. For instance such a $f$ can be found using optimal transport. (ps: I'm assuming by $\int x^n \mu(x)$ you mean $\int x^n d\mu$?)